# How to Text Mining Specific Data

Tags: regex, text, text-mining, extract

I have a list of ID with lengthy descriptions separated with semicolons.  The following is an example of one ID with its description.

```
  ID      Description 
O95831    activation of cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic process; apoptotic DNA fragmentation; apoptotic process; cell redox homeostasis; chromosome condensation; DNA catabolic process; intrinsic apoptotic signaling pathway in response to endoplasmic reticulum stress; mitochondrial respiratory chain complex I assembly; NAD(P)H oxidase activity; neuron apoptotic process; neuron differentiation; oxidoreductase activity, acting on NAD(P)H; positive regulation of apoptotic process; regulation of apoptotic DNA fragmentation
```

**Problem:** Figure out a way to text mining the description in which the expression "mitochondria" or "mitochondrial" or "mitochondrion" is mentioned.  Would regex be useful to solve this problem? or what other ways that might be useful?

**Expected Result:** extraction of the description which the the phrase "mitochondrial" is mentioned

```
O95831    ;mitochondrial respiratory chain complex I assembly;
```

Your help is appreciated,

Comment: I am familiar with Python/Perl

Comment: the Ruby regex selects the description perfectly.  What if the description "mitochondria" or "mitochondrial" or "mitochondrion" is not mention right after the presense of a semicolon ";"

Lets take this as an example:
`P55957 ;apoptotic mitochondrial changes; apoptotic process; brain development; `

Comment: I used such a regex as your expected output is presceded by a `;` . If it can occure anywhere, then just remove the `;` from the regex, it would match fine there after. `(\d+).*(\s(?:mitochondria|mitochondrial|mitochondrion)[^;]+;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```
(\d+).*(.\s(?:mitochondria|mitochondrial|mitochondrion)[^;]+;)
```

The capture groups 1 and 2 will contain

```
O95831    ;mitochondrial respiratory chain complex I assembly;
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/mR8xA7/1

Python code would be like

```
>>> re.findall(r"""(\d+).*(.\s(?:mitochondria|mitochondrial|mitochondrion)[^;]+;)""", str)
[('095831', '; mitochondrial respiratory chain complex I assembly;')]
```